# How to show SharePoint List Datasheet View in an application page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have an Application page which needs to show a custom Datasheet view. I am at loss on how to achieve this please?

The Datasheet view is one of many things that I want to display on this application page. Can it be done through SPGridView? Or what?

I am using SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2010, C#.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPGridView and then bind a datasource to it.
It's pretty much the same as you would do in ASP.Net

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView runat="server" ID="configData" width="50%" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">       
    <Columns>
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField runat="server" DataField="config_key" HeaderText="Configuration Item" />
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField runat="server" DataField="config_value" HeaderText="Configuration Value" />
    </Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

And the code behind would be something like:

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
var dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);

configData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
configData.DataBind();
```

You can also use field types available from ASP.Net like asp:HyperLinkField, asp:TemplateField depending on what you are trying to display.  SPGridView also has AutoGenerateColumns that you can set to true and let it display all the fields automatically but that depends on how well you datasource fields can be displayed to a user.